# AutoLayout CGAffineTransform iOS7 iOS8

Tags: ios7, storyboard, ios8, autolayout, cgaffinetransform

For hours I've been trying to figure why autolayout is breaking my constraint in iOS8 but not in iOS7 when I apply CGAffineTransformMakeScale. (I use Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317) with Storyboard and Autolayout).

The code :

```
TCTGridController *gridController = self.gridController;
stackController.view.frame = gridController.view.frame;
stackController.stackCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1);

[gridController.view.superview addSubview:stackController.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
    stackController.stackCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    [stackController.stackCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [stackController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}];
```

iOS7 result :

[image]

iOS8 result :

[image]

Constraint error on iOS8 :

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa126a9b100 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fa126a9a900]-(120)-[TCTCollectionView:0x7fa125139400]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fa126a8b500 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fa126a9a900(0)]>",
"<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x7fa126a8a960 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7fa126a9a900]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7fa126a9a810 )>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fa126c86840 h=--- v=--- 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Top' V:[UIView:0x7fa126a9a810]-(0)-|>"
)
```

Any ideas?

Alak

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CGAffineTransformIdentity behaves differently on ios7 and ios8. This has to do with auto-layout and size classes. The solution is to remove constraints that conflict with the animation on ios7.

```
// solve the constraint-animation problem
if(NSFoundationVersionNumber <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
    // iOS7 remove constraints that conflict with animation
    if (self.centerYAlignment != nil) {
    self.view.removeConstraint(self.centerYAlignment) //is an IBOutlet 
    }
} else {
    // iOS8 constraint animations are fine
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. CGAffineTransformMakeScale worked fine on iOS7 but caused a 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' error on iOS8. For me the solution was to add de view to the parent and call layoutIfNeeded on the subview prior to applying the transformation.

Before:

```
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);
```

After:

```
[view addSubview:subview];
[subview layoutIfNeeded];
subview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.001f, 0.001f);
```

Comment: thank you very much - wasted 2h of my life ;D `[subview layoutIfNeeded];` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

The problem come from

```
stackController.view.frame = gridController.view.frame;
```

and not from the CGAffineTransformMakeScale. Because I didn't uncheck "Resize view from NIB".
So to fix that I uncheck "Resize view from NIB" and add :

```
[stackController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:YES];
```